# Laravel 5 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\File' not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, illuminate-container

i get the following error:

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\File' not found
```

when using in laravel 5 Controller:

```
$files = File::files( $this->csvDir );
```

I have to add the [Filesystem](https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem) to `composer.json` and `config/app.php`. Somehow I use a misconfiguration.

That's what I changed:

#### composer.json

```javascript
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*", 
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "illuminate/filesystem": "5.*"  /* my try to repo */
    },
```

#### config/app.php

```php
    'providers' => [

    // [...] 
    // jerik 2015-04-17: get html Forms
    // http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', 
    'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', // try to add file
```

When I run `composer update`, it runs well, but there is no ouput that the Filesystem is downloaded. So my configuration is wrong, but I do not know the correct way.

Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: instead of `$files = File::files( $this->csvDir );` try `$files = \File::files( $this->csvDir );`

Comment: I think you haven't added the Facade in app.php

Comment: Shouldn't this have come with the framework?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First you shoud consider using built-in Storage facade. You don't need to include manually `Filesystem` unless you use S3 or Rackspace because it's already included by default - look at [Filesystem in Laravel 5 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem).

It also seems, that you should import `File` so try

```
use File;
```

or `\File` to solve the issue because now you are using File from current namespace and probably `File` is not defined in `App\Http\Controllers` namespace

Comment: I wish Laravel/artisan automatically added "use App\[Model];" to the top of the controller when it created it.

Comment: Undefined symbol 'File'.intelephense(1002)

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi, did you work out how to get rid of that error message in VSCode? I get the same, even though the code runs fine.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi Looks like new behaviour / bug introduced in recent version of Intellephense. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/59149877/1467680