# Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense Keep Showing Not Necessary Error

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

After the latest update of PHP Intelephense that I get today, the intelephense keep showing an error for an undefined symbol for my route (and other class too), there is no error like this before and it's bothering me.

Here is the error screenshot :

[image]

And this is my code :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'Membership', 'name' => 'user.'], function () {
    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');
    Route::patch('profile', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');
    Route::patch('change-password', 'ChangePasswordController@change')->name('change-password');
    Route::get('role', 'ProfileController@getRole')->name('profile.role');
    Route::get('summary', 'SummaryController@show')->name('summary');
    Route::get('reserved', 'AuctionController@reservedAuction')->name('reserved');
});
```

Actually there's no error in this code but the intelephense keeps showing an error so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I have reported an issue on this at the issue queue of the application - https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/885

Comment: If you're getting undefined error on Route in your `api.php`, see @user12483351's answer below. That fixed it for me. I'm on Intelephese 1.3.6.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Intelephense 1.3 added undefined type, function, constant, class constant, method, and property diagnostics, where previously in 1.2 there was only undefined variable diagnostics.

Some frameworks are written in a way that provide convenient shortcuts for the user but make it difficult for static analysis engines to discover symbols that are available at runtime.

Stub generators like https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper help fill the gap here and using this with Laravel will take care of many of the false diagnostics by providing concrete definitions of symbols that can be easily discovered.

Still, PHP is a very flexible language and there may be other instances of false undefined symbols depending on how code is written. For this reason, since 1.3.3, intelephense has config options to enable/disable each category of undefined symbol to suit the workspace and coding style.

These options are:

```js
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false,
    "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedVariables": true,
```

Setting all of these to false except `intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedVariables` will give version 1.2 behaviour. See the VSCode settings UI and search for `intelephense`.

Comment: Passed a few days with annoying alerts, now with recent update 1.3.3 - it's all ok.. Thanks @bmewburn

Comment: Thanks for separate config, for now I disabled undefinedMethods as intelephense can't detect laravel helper `auth()->user()` as class \App\User so calling method inside \App\User from `auth()->user()` will be detected as error. I just added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` in my routes to fix undefined symbol route error.

Comment: Thanks for this. For my setup, just diable `intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods` and `intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedType` works.

Comment: Just needed to generate the `_ide_helper.php` as suggested on docs.

Comment: For me, issue is gone after upgrading to 1.3.7 without any additional configuration. Thanks for your great work.

Comment: [laravel ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) solved the problem for me. just install it using composer and do `php artisan ide-helper:generate`

Comment: Press `ctrl+,` in VsCode. Search for `undefined` and uncheck all checkboxes where it says `Intellephense > Diagnostics`

Answer (score 171):

Version 1.3.0 has flaw IMO. 
Downgrade to version 1.2.3 fixes my problem. 
I'm on

- Laravel 5.1
- PHP 5.6.40

[image: Downgrade to Version 1.2.3]

Comment: Adding "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;" will actually solve the problem. As a general rule, for each symbol not found, just declare the approriate Facade.

Comment: @Alex There are other problems. You are gonna get errors for query scopes etc. This is not just facades.

Comment: Intelephense 1.3.3 adds further config options to suit your workspace and coding style. Each category of undefined diagnostic can now be enabled/disabled to suit.

Comment: In my opinion, the best resolution would be to upgrade to the latest version 1.3.11 (as of now) and then disable the undefined types checks in your settings file `"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,`.   This way, you do not get to lose all the other fixes implemented in the new release.

Comment: intelephense 1.4.0 also has an issue with referencing words like "Controller" and "View".  I rolled back to 1.3.11 and it works fine.

Answer (score 76):

If you see this immediately after adding a new Vendor class, be sure to run the VScode command (control-shift-P) `Index Workspace`

Comment: This appeared to work, but the next time I edited and saved my file it reappeared. :-(

Comment: Just found my own comment in answer to my problem !  I had forgotten this..

Comment: This worked for me as intellisense had not yet discovered my newly installed library.
On some Macs it's `command-shift-p`.
For more on the command pallete you can refer to: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette

Comment: This actually worked. I already had the project created and later installed packages but VSCode didn't seems to recognised until I see the `Index Workspace`

Comment: this worked for me as well. Definitely the first thing to try! It seems that what triggered the false intelliphense report of 'undefined symbol' was that I'd renamed some of the files. forcing 'index workspace' then seemed to correct for that.

Comment: Actually , I'm not certain what triggered the original issue .  IIt may have been renaming some files, or it may have been that I had hidden the 'vendor' folder in file explorer. either way index workspace eventually worked for me (once I'd made the vendor folder visible again for some reason)

Answer (score 53):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Warning Disappeared after importing the corresponding namespace.

**Version's**

- Larvel 6+
- vscode version 1.40.2
- php intelephense 1.3.1

Comment: This actually solves the problem. 
For commands inside console.php it works as well with:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

Comment: This is not laravel recommended. `laravel-ide-helper` configuration is.

Comment: Adding this solved the issue for `Route`, but I had the same error for `Auth`, so I added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` as well. Problem solved.

Answer (score 42):

In my case, for some reason, `vendor` folder was disabled on VS Code settings:

```json
    "intelephense.files.exclude": [
        "**/.git/**",
        "**/.svn/**",
        "**/.hg/**",
        "**/CVS/**",
        "**/.DS_Store/**",
        "**/node_modules/**",
        "**/bower_components/**",
        "**/vendor/**", <-- remove this line!
        "**/resources/views/**"
    ],
```

By removing the line containing `vendor` folder it works ok on version Intelephense 1.5.4

Comment: I also had to remove `"**/vendor/**/{Tests,tests}/**",` ; no idea how that line got in there.

Comment: I've done the same thing but still I'm getting error

Comment: @knb It's part of the default setting. The default contains `**/vendor/**/vendor/**` and `**/vendor/**/{Tests,tests}/**`

Comment: @mohammad_hosseini try opening the folder into VSCode before attempting to open the script individually.

Comment: i guess intelephense includes these folders by default, im not sure why, removing the vendor references from Intelephense › Files: Exclude fixed type hinting for me without installing ide-helper. do not remove them from Intelephense › References: Exclude
 or Intelephense › Rename: Exclude.

Answer (score 31):

This solution may help you if you know your problem is limited to Facades and you are running Laravel 5.5 or above.

**Install laravel-ide-helper**

`composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Add this conditional statement in your `AppServiceProvider` to register the helper class.

```
public function register()
{
    if ($this->app->environment() !== 'production') {
        $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` to generate a file to help the IDE understand Facades. You will need to restart Visual Studio Code.

**References**

https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/16

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: The probelm with this is you get duplicated definitions

Comment: intelephense stopped highlighting `Auth` after I restarted VS Code. I did exactly the steps shown in this answer. After restarting VS Code, give it a minute or two and the errors should clear.

Answer (score 26):

You don't need to downgrade you can:

Either disable undefined symbol diagnostics in the settings -- "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedSymbols": false .

Or use an ide helper that adds stubs for laravel facades. See https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: IDE Helper does solve the problems with Route closure or other closures, but you will run across other errors while using eloquent scopes etc.

Comment: So to solve an issue we need to loose true diagnostics. No way Josei!

Comment: I installed IDE Helper and generated the file as per instructions.. this is on a Laravel project. It appeared to change nothing and still had undefined symbols all over the place. So I downgraded to 1.2.3

Comment: Thanks for this advice - it seems now there is an even easier option - if you click on the cog for settings and scroll through the extensions settings for intelliphense there are various tick boxes and one is for undefined types.  

I was having so many errors of undefined types in my code as I'm working on a joomla template and I don't think intelliphense could see the various Joomla classes like JRequest, JFactory, etc... one addition that would be really useful is to tell it to only ignore undefined types that match a certain pattern (like in Joomla start with the letter J)

Comment: Disabling the "Undefined type" for Joomla doesn't seem the right way, but it does work. I tried to remove the /vendor folder from the exclude list but it had no effect.

Answer (score 25):

In my case I had to force `Intelephense` to index the workspace. Here's how I did it, in `VsCode`:

`ctrl + shift + p` > `Intelephense: Index workspace`

Answer (score 17):

There is an other solution since version 1.7.1 (2021-05-02)

You can now tell where intelephense should look for a dependency, for example vendor which is the most common.

```
"intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
    "vendor"
],
```

Furthermore, it even bypass the VSCode rule

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/vendor": true
},
```

You can read more [in the changelog here](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/blob/bd8bd154dddfb117b62f61bdbd825cd6629b7a35/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Where do you go to edit this?

Comment: You can add these rules inside the settings.json file. Press F1 and look for "Open user settings (JSON)"

Comment: Thanks @QuentiumYT - $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: This worked for me, after trying all the above suggestions with no luck. Thanks @QuentiumYT

Comment: Including the `vendor` directory in the VS Code settings was the secret sauce, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

1.3.1 fixed it.

Just update your extension and you should be good to go

Comment: Me too, is there a fix or should we downgrade?

Comment: For me it doesn't solves anything. Going back to 1.2.3 goes fine!

Comment: 1.3.1 still has this problem for me. 1.2.3 fixed it

Comment: I'm on 1.3.2 and still NOT fixed. Re-downgraded to 1.2.3.

Answer (score 13):

To those would prefer to keep it simple, stupid; If you rather get rid of the notices instead of installing a helper or downgrading, simply disable the error in your `settings.json` by adding this:

```
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false
```

Comment: Is there a "procedure" to find proper "disagnostics" for a given error message? Say, I have a legacy project and there are lots of messages like "Non static method 'builder' should not be called statically.intelephense(1036)". Which of options should disable these messages?

Answer (score 12):

Here is I solved:

Open the extension settings:

[image]

And search for the variable you want to change, and unchecked/checked it

[image]

The variables you should consider are:

```
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes 
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions         
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants         
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants 
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods 
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties 
intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedVariables
```

Comment: after trying this solution, I reset the "Index Workspace" thanks...

Comment: does not work on intelephense version 1.5.4, any fixes?

Comment: thank you! for my case, i tried the `laravel-ide-helper`, i just deactivated `intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods` because my livewire component was going crazy

Answer (score 6):

This is really a set of configurations for your editor to understand Laravel.

If you want to configure it all manually, here is the [repo](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). This is for both VS code and PhpStorm.

Or if you want you can download this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/andysong/laravel-helper).(I created)  recommended to install it globally.

And then just run `andylaravel setupIDE`. this will configure everything for you according to the fist repo.

Answer (score 5):

No, the errors occurs only after the Intelephense extension is automatically updated.

To solve the problem, you can downgrade it to the previous version by click "Install another version" in the Intelephense extension. There are no errors on version 1.2.3.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps anyone. I use it often. This will make your vscode "restart" without actually restarting. Part of this process will make your plugins update their cached indexes. `cmd+shift+p` or `ctrl+shift+p`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your web.php

Add this line of code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Then you are done, again if you got Auth error then add this line of code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem in **v1.7.1**. It was showing error on built-in functions. But just found the solution: go to extension setting `@ext:bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client` and disable one by one *Intelephense›Diagnostics:* and you will see the error showing will stop.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone going through these issues and uneasy about disabling a whole set of checks, there is a way to **pass your own custom signatures to Intelephense**.

*Copied from Intelephese repo's comment (by @KapitanOczywisty):

https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/892#issuecomment-565852100*

> For single workspace it is very simple, you have to create `.php` file
> with all signatures and intelephense will index them.
>
> If you want add stubs globally, you still can, but I'm not sure if
> it's intended *feature*. Even if `intelephense.stubs` throws warning about
> incorrect value you can in fact put there any **folder** name.
>
> ```
> {   
>    "intelephense.stubs": [
>        // ...
>        "/path/to/your/stub"   
>    ] 
> }
> ```
>
> Note: stubs are refreshed with this setting change.
>
> You can take a look at build-in stubs here:
> https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs

In my case, I needed dspec's `describe`, `beforeEach`, `it`... to don't be highlighted as errors, so I just included the file with the signatures `/directories_and_paths/app/vendor/bin/dspec` in my VSCode's workspace settings, which had the function declarations I needed:

```php
function describe($description = null, \Closure $closure = null) {
}

function it($description, \Closure $closure) {
}

// ... and so on
```

Comment: ...`(I use VSCode, but it should work the same for Visual Studio Code)`... Huh?

Comment: Yeah, messed up the names, thought the question was about Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Add the above **Namespace**

Comment: @francisco how does declaring a class alias violate a PSR standard? Which PSR?

Comment: @francisco "above" is referencing the declaration in the example. In other words, "Add the namespace, as shown above."

Comment: Regardless, this answer was [already given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59187744/1255289) the day after the question was asked...

Answer (score 1):

**The only working solution I found is:**

Set language mode to Blade (use extension: **Laravel Blade formatter**)
It will resolve the issue. Otherwise, follow this procedure.

These classes don't exist in the workspace. Laravel creates them at runtime. As such they are reported as undefined. The solution is to either provide stub definitions

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

or turn off the diagnostics (intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following seemed to have addressed the issue.

a) Updated to latest version 1.3.5 and re-enabled all the diagnosis settings.

I was still getting the messages

b) Added the vendor folder with the dependent libraries to the workspace

This seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: You could use `laravel-ide-helper`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using Symfony inside Drupal. Would laravel-ide-helper help?

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed my own issue. by going file > preferences
and I search for intelliphense
The section that has file to exclude, I noticed `vendor` folder was added.
I removed it, now all my laravel files are indexed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to deactivate the lastly installed extension, then deactivate Intelephense and reactivate it, and it worked for me.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I just closed and reopened the VS. And now Itelliphense does not complain.
This procedure is called: Shut-down And Turn-on (SAT) :)