# VSCode Intelliphense not working properly with Laravel Projects

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

In VSCode the PHP intelephense extension version 1.3.7 marks the laravel Facades as classes not found. 
Before if you import a Facade like this:

```
use Log;
```

and then use it in the file like this:

```
Log::info('some message');
```

which is correct there were no issues. Now every usage is marked as a syntax error and you have to import the fully qualified name like the following for the error to go away.

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

Also it didn't used to complain about the Eloquent class's methods like `find` or `where` etc but now it underlines them as methods not defined.

Is there a way for the extension to ignore these?

Comment: I know it's a little late. But I'm struggling with this, too. Maybe you are looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266972/9994944 (Setting some of the Intelephense PHP options to false in settings.json)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`.

it makes VScode to refer **Facade** files.

example)

```
    "require-dev": {
        ...
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.7",
        ...
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which is really a life saver here is the `php namespace resolver` extension, it gives you all the possible options that you want as a dropdown menu.

Here is the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver)

[image: Here I don't have a the required category controller in my api.php routes, what I just need to do is go to my route where my controller is defined]

[image: Right click on my class which I want to add and click import]

[image: If there are multiple options, VS Code will show me a drop down from command palette to, I just have to select the right one and simply add it]

Comment: Please consider adding examples as well.