# Intelephense stub won't load in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I have some helper functions that I use everywhere in a CakePHP 2 application. They are underlined with red and reported as 'undefined functions' in the console. I know I can just [ignore the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266972/547489), but I would like to have it working properly going forward, especially if I can manage to get alt-click working with it for models.

In my VS Code `settings.json`, I have the following:

```
"intelephense.stubs": [
        "apache", "bcmath", "bz2", "calendar", "com_dotnet", "Core", "ctype", "curl", "date", "dba", "dom", "enchant", "exif", "FFI", "fileinfo", "filter", "fpm", "ftp", "gd", "gettext", "gmp", "hash", "iconv", "imap", "intl", "json", "ldap", "libxml", "mbstring", "meta", "mysqli", "oci8", "odbc", "openssl", "pcntl", "pcre", "PDO", "pdo_ibm", "pdo_mysql", "pdo_pgsql", "pdo_sqlite", "pgsql", "Phar", "posix", "pspell", "readline", "Reflection", "session", "shmop", "SimpleXML", "snmp", "soap", "sockets", "sodium", "SPL", "sqlite3", "standard", "superglobals", "sysvmsg", "sysvsem", "sysvshm", "tidy", "tokenizer", "xml", "xmlreader", "xmlrpc", "xmlwriter", "xsl", "Zend OPcache", "zip", "zlib", "wordpress",
        "./Config/core.php"
    ],
```

It's my understanding that it is allowed to import custom .php files as stubs so that Intelephense recognizes them. However, no path that I enter will work. I have tried everything I can think of:

1. C:/wamp64/www/MY_APP/app/
2. ../App/Config
3. simply not adding .php, simply not adding the file at all
4. So many more!

How can I get Intelephense to recognize core.php, which essentially just holds a bunch of settings and some helper functions defined as, for example:

```
// just an alias for json decode
function jdec($json) {
    return json_decode($json, 1, 512, JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE);
}
```

Note: I am sure my difficulty with Intelephense is *not* strictly related to the CakePHP 2 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add CakePHP 2 location path to `intelephense.environment.includePaths` setting.

Here's an example of my workspace config for similar situation. I have the libraries I include outside of my workspace, so I specify paths to those like this:

```
"intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
  "/path/to/lib1",
  "/path/to/lib2"
]
```

After this, all the functions from included libraries are properly indexed by Intelephense and no longer marked as `undefined`.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is more for lib connectivity. My `core.php` is full of helper functions that I simply need to import, you could imagine it as a simple include for a "`global_functions.php`" solution in the vanilla PHP days of olde.

Comment: So have you tried to add your `core.php` location to `intelephense.environment.includePaths` like I suggested? You might need to restart VS Code in order for changes to take effect.

Comment: Yep :( and I went pretty crazy with it just to be sure.
`"intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
        "../lib/",
        "../app/Config/",
        "../app/Config/core.php",
        "Config/",
        "Config/core.php",
        "./Config/",
        "./Config/core.php",
    ]` And I am aware it's a relative path.

Comment: I'm sure yours is the actual answer: turns out I had a function in `core.php` that made Intelephense ignore the entire file. That function simply needed to re-open PHP with a `<?php` rather than `<?`.