# Laravel errors '; expected' and 'Unexpected Unknown' 437 times

Tags: php, laravel

I just opened the Laravel project I'm working on and came across this (see image).
I don't even know where to start solving it.
Can anybody give me a slight direction with what it might have to do and where I could start solving it?
(Happens also when opening other Laravel projects.)

[image]

I don't know whether this is relevant for this problem, but I stopped working on the project due to an error with XAMPP. I had to re-install it and it is working now. I did not keep any of the data tables, since they were only filled with some dummy data. I just wanted to run migrations again.

Thank you so much! I'm happy to give more details if necessary!

Comment: This looks like the php syntax check uses a pretty old php version. Have a look at the settings: Preferences > Extensions > PHP > Edit in settings.json. You can set the path to the php version there. (Or fix the php path in your user paths)

Comment: @kuh-chan I added "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/xampp/php/php.exe" in settings.json but after some time everything went red again (even after restarting both vscode and laptop)

Comment: what extensions do you use?

Comment: I disabled the extensions one by one and it must have something to do with the PHP Intellisense extension. I even tried Intelephense instead but some of the errors are still shown. I set "intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes" to false as this answer here suggested and it worked for now, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266972/9994944

Answer (score 4):

so... I was getting the same problem. I just removed the PHP Intellisense and installed the PHP Intelephense. It worked for me and I find the Intelephense too better.
I hope it works for you!