# Laravel auth()->user()->posts()->create($data); > Undefined method 'post'.intelephense(1013)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've been following a tutorial for 2 hours, and now I have a problem. The tutorial is using an older version of Laravel. I'm creating an Instagram clone, and want to create posts.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

**PostsController**

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);
    
    /* I got an error at this line saying undefined method post() */
    auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should place the `posts()` method inside the `User` model instead of `UserController`.

Comment: My bad I meant to write user unstead of usercontroller. I corrected in the question now but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common issue caused by Intellephense.
Seems to be answered over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59266972/14440607

In essence, an IDE helper will generate code to help your IDE give accurate suggestions.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29900493)