# VSCode intelephense's fake errors - Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-livewire

That's not a breaking-mind thing but it's really annoying:

```
public function render(){
    return view('home')->extends('layout.app')->section('content');
}
```

The error is

> **Undefined method 'extends'.**

That's not even the only "fake error" i get but it's the only one in this project.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877/visual-studio-code-php-intelephense-keep-showing-not-necessary-error