# How to deal with laravel class error in vscode?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I prefer to use vscode for the laravel project.

I am a beginner and recently I got work on a company project. so I need to clone the project. but I am getting a class error in my vscode but the project running perfectly.

I can solve the error by importing class by importing Illuminate\Support\Facades\ClassName.

The problem is I have to go into each file and Import the required class in my PHP file. that is not ok.

I am using PHP intelephence extension for the autosuggestion. if I disable the intelephence I am not getting this class error. but not getting auto-completion.

How can I deal with this issue?.

Give me some suggestions and solutions to deal with these issues.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense Keep Showing Not Necessary Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877/visual-studio-code-php-intelephense-keep-showing-not-necessary-error)

Comment: Because `Validator` class(facade) is defined under aliases in config/app.php. Which cannot be identified by php intelliphense.

Comment: Try [laravel ide helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgykurian.laravel-ide-helper) for VSC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import individually because the plugin will not resolve the imports in cases where there are conflicts i.e., classes, interfaces having the same name.

Even if it does resolve, the project is prone to have issues, which will be hard to debug at times.

e.g.,
[same class and interface name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF2dk.png)

**Note:** Always import things at the beginning of the file instead of accessing it in the functions multiple times. By doing so, you can alias different imports.

**Import shortcut for vs code**
place the cursor on the thing to import and
Press CTRL + ALT + i on Windows / CTRL + Option + i on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these awesome [extensions](https://github.com/mahmoudmohamedramadan/Backend-Roadmap#awesome-extensions-), these will help you more

**Please note** that there are some errors that VS Code generates because VS Code not intelligence to much to know that these classes or methods are exists So, you can use [`@see`](https://pear.php.net/package/PhpDocumentor/docs/latest/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.see.pkg.html) and [`@method`](https://pear.php.net/package/PhpDocumentor/docs/latest/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html) to resolve these errors