# Laravel auth()->user->posts()->create($data); > Undefined property

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to backend development so I am trying to do a lot of tutorials on the internet to get the hang of this.

ATM I am trying to do a 2 year old tutorial for an Instagram Clone so I am trying to follow it while using the documentation for the current version of laravel to update and run my code.

I am trying to create posts, my Route in web.php is

```
Route::post('/post', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'store']);
```

My store function in PostController.php

```
    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
           'caption' => 'required',
           'image' => 'required|image' 
        ]);

        auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);

        Post::create($data);

        dd(request()->all());
    }
```

In the User.php I also defined

```
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

It keeps telling me "unidentified method 'posts'. intelephense(1013)

I have searched and found similar problems with this part of the tutorial but I couldn't fix it and I was wondering if it's just another case of different version problem .

I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you!

I am trying to make the post command work and while following the tutorial, it gave me this error saying the function is not defined.

Comment: Are you getting an actual error or only the message in your code editor? Have a look [Visual Studio Code PHP Intelephense Keep Showing Not Necessary Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877/visual-studio-code-php-intelephense-keep-showing-not-necessary-error) Maybe try to run your code and check if it works.

Comment: If it is an error on your IDE, just ignore it, because it is kot smart enought to understand you are calling something that does exist. If it is an actual PHP error from Laravel, then share it please

Comment: Hi, you can check the controller name is PostsController or PostController.

Comment: What editor to you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quess the problem is your editor, I am testing your issue in PhpStorm and anythings works fine for me, after that I do a little research and I found this post, i think you have the same problem, check it:

[link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/undefined-method-documentationsintelephense1013)

Comment: Might be that indeed, I'll check out and see if PHPStorm handles it better. 
Thank you for the reply and the link.