# How to solve versions problem in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, version, laravel-5.8

I have an old Laravel project with version 5.8, and I've downloaded PHP with version 7.1.33, but these errors continue to appear
I can't do anything with these errors!

[image: route file from the project]

I've tried to create a new Laravel project with version 5.8 and it run without errors
But I need the old project

Comment: Don't forget toe include the Route facade on top of your file. Also, you can make use of Route::view instead of Route::get to link a view without a controller.

Comment: "these errors continue to appear" - what does that mean? You've only shared a screenshot of your code, not a single error message. Also, why is this tagged with Composer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found the solution in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877/visual-studio-code-php-intelephense-keep-showing-not-necessary-error
Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Write below line on top of your `web.php` file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: I added this line but nothing changed