# laravel-version:11.1.1(Undefined method 'safe'.intelephense(P1013))

Tags: php, laravel

[Undefined method 'safe'.intelephense(P1013)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34DNQ.png)

```
  $user_input = $request->only(["name", "email", "password"]);
        $profile_input = $request->except(["name", "email", "password", "password_confirmation"]);
```

but when I used it, my postman gave an error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'last_name' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `profiles`

Comment: Those are two different things: The intelephense error is only [VSCode not knowing the functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149877/visual-studio-code-php-intelephense-keep-showing-not-necessary-error), and you'll need to make some tweaks for the IDE. The default value is because you have a `last_name` field on profiles, but you're not passing in a value, and it doesn't have a nullable or default value.